# get value into output variable when executing stored procedure through dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i am using sql server 2008 r2, I have created a dynamic stored procedure because this is my requirement to implement to filteration of data based on certain conditions. I am not able to get value into @RecordCount

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getAssetListAudit]
    @type nvarchar(20),
    @typeid nvarchar(5),
    @clientId nvarchar(5),
    @PageIndex nvarchar(5),
    @PageSize nvarchar(5),
    @RecordCount nvarchar(5) output 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SQL    nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL ='

select ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ad.arid ASC )
AS rownum, ad.arid,ad.ast_code,ad.ast_descp,isnull(cat.name,'''') ''cat'',ISNULL(loc.name,'''') ''loc'',isnull(gp.name,'''') ''grp'',
isnull(cc.name,'''') ''cc'' ,
ad.ast_qty ''qty'' into #Results
from tbl_AssetDetails ad
left join tbl_Category cat on ad.ast_cat = cat.catid
left join tbl_Subcategory scat on ad.ast_subcat = scat.subcatid
left join tbl_Location loc on loc.lid = ad.ast_loc
left join tbl_Group gp on gp.gid = ad.ast_grp
left join tbl_CostCenter cc on cc.ccid = ad.ast_costcen
where ad.ast_status not in (3,-1) AND ad.clientId = '+@clientId+' AND ' 

IF(@type='cat')
SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.ast_cat='+@typeid+' AND '
IF(@type='subcat')
SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.ast_subcat='+@typeid+' AND '
IF(@type='loc')
SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.ast_loc='+@typeid+' AND '
IF(@type='grp')
SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.ast_grp='+@typeid+' AND '
IF(@type='cc')
SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.ast_costcen='+@typeid+' AND '
IF(@type='ast')
SET @SQL = @SQL +' ad.arid='+@typeid+' AND '

SET @SQL = @SQL +' 1=1 '
SET @SQL =@SQL + ' SELECT '+@RecordCount+' = count(*) FROM #Results '
SET @SQL  = @SQL +' SELECT * FROM #Results WHERE rownum 
BETWEEN('+@PageIndex+' -1) * '+@PageSize+' + 1 AND((('+@PageIndex+' -1) * '+@PageSize+'+ 1) + '+@PageSize+') - 1 '

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' drop table #Results '

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @RecordCount OUTPUT
```

END

I am not able to get value into @RecordCount and subsequently no result set.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the value to the OUTPUT parameter:

```
SET @SQL =@SQL + ' SELECT @RecordCount = count(*) FROM #Results; '
```

You also need to pass the parameter definitions to sp_executesql as in @wannuanguo's answer. You should use also use parameters for @typeid, @pageindex, etc. too instead of literals in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Add the second parameter for sp_executesql:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@RecordCount nvarchar(5) output',@RecordCount OUTPUT
```